# Neo4j Server size grows even when all data deleted

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently testing out **Neo4j server** interacting with Python through py2neo. I have been running many tests. At the start of each test, I delete all nodes and relations from the database and recreate nodes and relations every time. I have been doing this numerous times. Even while everything is deleted and the database is 'empty', the **size of the server keeps on growing**. Is there a way to reduce the size of the server so that it reflects more or less the size of the actual data in the database? I just want to avoid that the size on my disk explodes.

Comment: Could you please show us content of your graph.db directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibility are Logical logs or standard logs.

If you are using Neo4j just for testing I suggest to turn off them.

**neo4j.properties**

```
keep_logical_logs=false
```

Check size of

- neo4j/data/graph.db/messages.log
- neo4j/log/graph.db/console.log

Comment: The log file and neostore.xxxx.db files were growing. I got rid of them in the test environment and also changed the server config settings to store fewer of them.